# OAuth1 stopped working

Tags: security, oauth2, isv, gack

Our SalesForce app is connected to GAE via OAuth1, each time we provision new account we make this connection.

Lately we start getting this errors when trying to establish the connection:

> An internal server error has occurred
>   An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.

Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com!

Error ID: 1373542206-205158 (-545706004)

Did you encounter this?

**Update**

After talking to SalesForce tech support, apparently they succeed in establishing this connection, although we still do not. very strange, more updates soon.

**Update 2**

Still online with SalesForce tech support, apparently the Summer 2016 release has a new feature called

> Improved Session Security for OAuth 1.0 Token Exchanges

[Link to the release note](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_security_auth_oauth1_flow_changes.htm)

I think it prevents OAuth 1.0 from working properly, I have just asked to disable it

Comment: looks like a [gack](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html) to me. You can raise a case with given error id.

Comment: This gack prevents me from creating OAuth2 connection on Summer 2016 versions, what would you do? how do I raise a case?

Comment: You need to have a partner login to raise a case.

Comment: I created a case and showed their technical support this issue is reproduced. The question is if they are capable of solving this issue, from my past experience if I will not resolve this issue myself, this issue will remain open

Comment: I think they are very much capable.It's just how early you get there response.Good luck from me :)

Comment: @Mr.Frodo I hope you are right, I am discussing this issue with SalesForce support (for one week now), so far I got to Tier-3 support, I hope they can understand the issue.